# Can I just add Card Details without charging the customer with Stripe?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I need my customers to add their credit card info, but I don't want to charge them right away. Is there any way, I can add their details to charge later when using Stripes `checkout` solution and just store their card token first?

I am using Laravel Cashier on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

with Laravel cashier it is realy hard to do that. You have to tweak it a little bit..

But with Stripe you can create customers and charge them later with info.

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2");

// Create a Customer:
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
    'source' => 'tok_mastercard',
    'email' => 'paying.user@example.com',
]);

// Charge the Customer instead of the card:
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
    'amount' => 1000,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'customer' => $customer->id,
]);

// YOUR CODE: Save the customer ID and other info in a database for later.

// When it's time to charge the customer again, retrieve the customer ID.
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
    'amount' => 1500, // $15.00 this time
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'customer' => $customer_id, // Previously stored, then retrieved
]);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Set Stripe API key
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_HGJJKJLJLKHKJHGJHGKH");

// Retrieve Customer
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve("cus_KJHKJHJKJKHKJHKJ");

// Create new card
$data = [
    "type"        => "card",
    "card"        => [
        "exp_month" => "01",
        "exp_year"  => "20",
        "number"    => "4242424242424242",
        "cvc"       => "123",
    ],
];
$card = \Stripe\Source::create($data);

// Assign the created card to the customer
$customer->sources->create(["source" => $card['id']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter card details

```
 $token=Token::create(['card'=>
   [
        'number'=>'4242 4242 4242 4242',
        'exp_month'=>12,
        'exp_year'=>2022,
        'cvc'=>121
   
    ],
  )];
**//Set Stripe API key**
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

           $stripe=$stripe->customers->createSource(
            $customer->id,
            ['source' => $token->id
        ]);
```

reference
https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).